# I am trying to install google-colab for working with gemini api(storing api) but am getting an unexpected error

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, google-gemini, google-generativeai

The error is as follows-

```
Collecting pandas~=0.24.0 (from google-colab)
  Using cached pandas-0.24.2.tar.gz (11.8 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      C:\Users\mkpan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j73lpax3\pandas_935025fbfe6c48039f7095432e24aeb1\setup.py:12: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
        import pkg_resources
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\mkpan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j73lpax3\pandas_935025fbfe6c48039f7095432e24aeb1\setup.py", line 732, in <module>
          version=versioneer.get_version(),
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\mkpan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j73lpax3\pandas_935025fbfe6c48039f7095432e24aeb1\versioneer.py", line 1409, in get_version    
          return get_versions()["version"]
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\mkpan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j73lpax3\pandas_935025fbfe6c48039f7095432e24aeb1\versioneer.py", line 1343, in get_versions   
          cfg = get_config_from_root(root)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\mkpan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j73lpax3\pandas_935025fbfe6c48039f7095432e24aeb1\versioneer.py", line 399, in get_config_from_root
          parser = configparser.SafeConfigParser()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      AttributeError: module 'configparser' has no attribute 'SafeConfigParser'. Did you mean: 'RawConfigParser'?
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I even installed pandas separately and it worked but when I try to download google.colab or google-colab it throws this error

Could you please help me?

Comment: what's your python version? Also your path looks unfamiliar

Comment: I have python 3.9 also i dont understand what you mean by my path looking unfamiliar(i am a beginner)

Comment: This package seems to be compatible with Python 2.7 - 3.6. Can you downgrade to 3.6? https://pypi.org/project/google-colab/